# Parsing Dictionary Object and Creating MySQL Table through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, dictionary

Currently, I have this dictionary object in my PHP script that was posted to my PHP implemented server through my iOS app:

```
{"command":"save","classname":"GameScore","cheatMode":"0","playerName":"SeanPlott","score":"1337"}
```

Now I need to create a MySQL table based off the data...

Here is my attempt to parse the data but all i get are the objects, not the keys...

```
foreach( $text as $stuff ) {
    if( is_array( $stuff ) ) {
        echo json_encode($stuff);
        foreach( $stuff as $thing ) {
            echo json_encode($thing);
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode($stuff);
    }
}
```

Heres the result... `"save""GameScore""0""SeanPlott""1337"`

This is what I plan on making as a query

```
$result = query("INSERT INTO '%s'('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') 
                    VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s')", $classname, $key1, $key2, $key3, $key4, 
                                                    $object1, $object2, $$object3, $object4);
```

But the query should be dynamic, since the dictionary object can have 1 or many keys/objects...

So I figure I need to implement a parsing for loop that generates the query within the array and outputs a string which is the query...

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix my parser?

**EDIT:** heres my query function to handle MYSQL

```
function query() {
    global $link;
    $debug = false; 
    $args = func_get_args();
    $sql = array_shift($args);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($args); $i++) {
        $args[$i] = urldecode($args[$i]);
        $args[$i] = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $args[$i]);
    }

    $sql = vsprintf($sql, $args);

    if ($debug) print $sql;

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    if (mysqli_errno($link) == 0 && $result) {  
        $rows = array();

        if ($result !== true)
            while ($d = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                array_push($rows,$d);

        return array('result' => $rows);

    } else {
        return array('error' => 'Database error');
    }
}
```

EDIT: Took me a while and a lot of help but I completed it... It takes care of the case of spaces in values and adds '`' characters around the keys if there corresponding value contains a space...

```
$raw_data = '{"command":"save","classname":"GameScore","cheatMode":"0","playerName":"Sean Plott","score":"1337"}';
$data = json_decode($raw_data, true);
$columns = array_slice(array_keys($data), 2);
array_shift($data);
$table_title = array_shift($data);

$values = array();
$num = 0;
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($value, " ") !== false) $columns[$num] = "`".$columns[$num]."`";
    $num = $num + 1;
    $values[] = (!is_numeric($value)) ? "'".$value."'" : $value;
}

$final_statement = "INSERT INTO " . $table_title . " (".implode(', ', $columns).") VALUES (".implode(', ', $values).")";
echo $final_statement;
```

If anyone sees any way to optimize this or make it cleaner... please feel free to post something!

Thanks again for everyones input!

Comment: What are you trying to do in your loop? Your input looks like json so just decoding it once should give you all you need. Note that you would need white-lists to validate the table- and column names and a prepared statement for the values.

Comment: I am attempting to parse the keys AND the objects... currently I am only echoing the objects.. not the keys... and I posted my query function to handle inserting new tables into mysql

Comment: I fail to see what the problem is, `json_decode()` and `foreach($var as $key => $value)` is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a simple `json_decode()` and `implode()` to format it and prepare to insertion. Consider this example:

```
$raw_data = '{"command":"save","classname":"GameScore","cheatMode":"0","playerName":"SeanPlott","score":"1337"}';
$data = json_decode($raw_data, true);
$columns = array_keys($data); // get the columns

$final_statement = "INSERT INTO `table` (".implode(', ', $columns).") VALUES ('".implode("','", $data)."')";
echo $final_statement;
// outputs: INSERT INTO `table` (command, classname, cheatMode, playerName, score) VALUES ('save','GameScore','0','SeanPlott','1337')
```

EDIT: Suppose your columns has int types (especially the ones that has numeric values). For whatever reason it doesn't work, because of a mismatch, if so, you could probably do this. Consider this example:

```
$raw_data = '{"command":"save","classname":"GameScore","cheatMode":"0","playerName":"SeanPlott","score":"1337"}';
$data = json_decode($raw_data, true);
$columns = array_keys($data); // get the columns

$values = array();
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    // if not numeric, add quotes, if not, leave it as it is
    $values[] = (!is_numeric($value)) ? "'".$value."'" : $value;
}

$final_statement = "INSERT INTO `table` (".implode(', ', $columns).") VALUES (".implode(', ', $values).")";
echo $final_statement;
// outputs: INSERT INTO `table` (command, classname, cheatMode, playerName, score) VALUES ('save', 'GameScore', 0, 'SeanPlott', 1337)
// Note: numbers has no qoutes
```

Comment: I was able to solve the problem... But this answer is so much more simplified and uses the PHP functions very well... Thank you @kevinabelita!

Comment: Could I possibly as for an updated answer on how to solve the issue of spacing within the values? For example, SeanPlott is actually supposed to be Sean Plott and MySQL throws me an error... I figure I can solve it but once I do ...  would like to see a better solution :)

Comment: @jsetting32 i have an edit regarding data types being inserted, might be useful too

Comment: How about a problem regarding a table that has not been created yet? I would like for a table to be created if necessary, dynamically. Any ideas?

Comment: @jsetting32 what do you mean a problem with a table that hasn't been created yet? of course you can dynamically create a table with different column names, but the length and the type, you're gonna have to feed them manually, my reasoning is, how would you distinguish which is an int, or a varchar with just column names